# In Termux: how to update manual page database: "mandb" went =>?=> "mandoc" gone =>?=>

Tags: termux

The cause: manpage of aptitude is installed (android 12, termux 118, 6.2.1 PRoot-Distro, ubuntu 23.10) but "man aptitude" does not find it; yet "man -l pathfilename" does display it.

And some other signs that mandb should be updated.

Why update of manual page database is not possible. How to repaire?

Regards